# What is the difference between PowerManager and JobScheduler API in Android?

Tags: android, powermanager, android-jobscheduler

Hy everybody!

What is the main difference between PowerManager and JobScheduler API in Android?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are generally unrelated. `JobScheduler`, under the covers, uses a `WakeLock`, and apps can also acquire a `WakeLock` from `PowerManager`.